# Rectangle inscribed in a right triangle with largest perimeter

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

> Which rectangle has the largest perimeter inscribed in a right-angled triangle of legs $3$ and $4$, where one of the sides lies on the hypotenuse?

I've done the calculation for the largest area and found the value of the sides of the rectangle, using a derivative, and found the values of 6/5 and 5/2 but I don't know how to answer the final part of the question.

Comment: I studied French, but it's of no help in translating Portuguese! Can you please translate the title?

Comment: I've studied Spanish and it's close enough to Portuguese that I could translate.

Comment: @phsubi If your English is not good, it would be better if you could at least try phrasing the question in English. If there are any errors, we will help you correct them.

Comment: I didn't get "two sides of the rectangle lie on the hypotenuse".

Comment: @TobyMak (According to Google) "um dos lados" -> "one of sides". Also, we have https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857896/what-is-the-largest-perimeter-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-right-angled-triangle-of now

Comment: @player3236 Ah right, I forgot 'dos' is a contraction of 'de os' which means 'of the'.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB = 3, AC = 4, BC = 5$ in $\Delta ABC$. Draw the altitude from point $A$ to $BC$, and label their intersection $M$. Also, let the inscribed rectangle be $PQRS$, where $P$ lies on $AB$, $Q$ lies on $AC$, $R$ lies on $MC$ and $S$ lies on $BM$.

Now the altitude $AM$ is $\frac{4 \times 3}{5}$ (can you find the area two different ways?) Then $BM = \frac{9}{5}$ and $CM = \frac{16}{5}$. The height of the rectangle is given by $\frac{PS}{BS} = \frac{AM}{BM} \Rightarrow \frac{h}{BS} = \frac{12/5}{9/5}$, so $h = \frac{4}{3} BS$. Similarly, the height of the rectangle is also given by $\frac{QR}{RC} = \frac{AM}{MC}$, so $\frac{h}{RC} = \frac{12/5}{16/5} \Rightarrow h = \frac{3}{4} RC$. Equating the two, $\frac{4}{3} BS = \frac{3}{4} RC \Rightarrow RC = \frac{16}{9} BS$.

Let $BS = x$. Then the perimeter is given by $2 \left(\frac{4}{3}x + \frac{9}{5} - x + \frac{16}{5} - \frac{16}{9}x \right)$, where there are restrictions on $x$. Can you continue?